# Creating a sequence column with ORDER BY using MySql 5.5.62

Tags: mysql

I'm inputting the following query using MySql 5.5.62 to creating a sequence column with ORDER BY using MySql 5.5.62

What I'm trying to achieve is to by adding a sequence column that I can sort my results on instead of sorting on multiple columns. It's based on an ORDER BY clause involving 1 column.

```
UPDATE `dotable` t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        ( @rn := @rn + 1 ) AS pPrio,
        pDateHH,
        sID 
    FROM
        `dotable`,
        ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) AS x 
    ORDER BY
        pDateHH ASC 
    ) q ON t.sID = q.sID 
    SET t.pPrio = q.pPrio
    WHERE DATE(t.pDateHH) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

I need this result

```
+-------+---------------------+
| pPrio | pDateHH             |
+-------+---------------------+
|     1 | 2021-09-16 18:40:02 |
|     2 | 2021-09-16 19:00:20 |
|     3 | 2021-09-16 19:20:47 |
|     4 | 2021-09-16 20:00:59 |
|     5 | 2021-09-16 20:01:48 |
|     6 | 2021-09-16 20:20:31 |
|     7 | 2021-09-16 20:40:05 |
|     8 | 2021-09-16 21:17:27 |
|     9 | 2021-09-16 21:20:03 |
|    10 | 2021-09-16 21:40:24 |
|    11 | 2021-09-16 22:00:09 |
|    12 | 2021-09-16 22:38:03 |
|    13 | 2021-09-16 22:40:03 |
|    14 | 2021-09-16 23:02:25 |
|    15 | 2021-09-16 23:20:02 |
|    16 | 2021-09-16 23:58:58 |
|     1 | 2021-09-17 00:00:06 |
|     2 | 2021-09-17 00:22:53 |
|     3 | 2021-09-17 00:40:05 |
|     4 | 2021-09-17 01:00:44 |
|     5 | 2021-09-17 01:20:04 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Instead of

```
+-------+---------------------+
| pPrio | pDateHH             |
+-------+---------------------+
|     1 | 2021-09-16 18:40:02 |
|     2 | 2021-09-16 19:00:20 |
|     3 | 2021-09-16 19:20:47 |
|     4 | 2021-09-16 20:00:59 |
|     5 | 2021-09-16 20:01:48 |
|     6 | 2021-09-16 20:20:31 |
|     7 | 2021-09-16 20:40:05 |
|     8 | 2021-09-16 21:17:27 |
|     9 | 2021-09-16 21:20:03 |
|    10 | 2021-09-16 21:40:24 |
|    11 | 2021-09-16 22:00:09 |
|    12 | 2021-09-16 22:38:03 |
|    13 | 2021-09-16 22:40:03 |
|    14 | 2021-09-16 23:02:25 |
|    15 | 2021-09-16 23:20:02 |
|    16 | 2021-09-16 23:58:58 |
|    17 | 2021-09-17 00:00:06 |
|    18 | 2021-09-17 00:22:53 |
|    19 | 2021-09-17 00:40:05 |
|    20 | 2021-09-17 01:00:44 |
|    21 | 2021-09-17 01:20:04 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

Any suggestion?

My table structure and the update query below on **[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mWSzAdoi9H2xH7GkMzVYFR/1)**, which offers MySQL 5

Comment: I suggest upgrading to MySQL 8+ and using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for reply. But the upgrading to MySQL 8 it depends on the hosting provider

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. I suspect that you'd be better off addressing the original sorting problem than implementing a sequence number.

Comment: @EdwardSheriffCurtis please check my below query and let me know any query regard this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As row_number() does not support lower version so alternative use of row_number in below query. As compare with date so consider a default date.

```
-- MySQL(5.5 & 5.6)
UPDATE dotable d
JOIN (SELECT @row_no:=CASE WHEN @db_names=DATE(d.pDateHH) THEN @row_no+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number
     , @db_names:= DATE(d.pDateHH) date_val
    , d.pDateHH
    , d.sID
FROM dotable d,
(SELECT @row_no := 0,@db_names:='1900-01-01') x
ORDER BY DATE(d.pDateHH)) p
   ON d.sID = p.sID
SET d.pPrio = p.row_number
    WHERE DATE(d.pDateHH) = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f9def1b6a12976bbceb30a6984726ead